# C# Бибилиотека для парсинга javascript

Tags: c#, v8

Я пишу программу на C# для примитивного анализа кода(рекурсивное прохождение по Javascript AST дереву ). Раньше я решил использовать Jint из сайта Github , но там сборка не имеет Visitor паттерна , который необходим для гибкого прохода по синтаксическому дереву объектов , представляющие элементы кода js. Прошло время и я нашёл другую сборку Jint , где есть поддержка паттерна Visitor:

https://github.com/cosh/Jint/blob/master/Jint/IJintVisitor.cs

Но эта сборка во время работы не хочет читать стандартные функции или объекты вроде таких как: window.onload() , Console.log() , alert() , parseInt() , document , Math и.т.д. , которые уже есть в движке V8 (это так к слову). И поэтому когда в C# при помощи Jint пытаюсь парсить Javascript код , в котором введена одна из этих перечисленных выше объектов или функций(из v8) по Ast дереву , тогда вылетают исключения (вроде этого "underfined object member 'window'" и.т.д.)

Поэтому пожалуйста скажите : какая C# библиотека для интерпретации Javascript

- имеет a Visitor паттерн(для пользовательского рекурсивного прохода по синтаксическому дереву)
- включает v8 движок или поддержку на него(для успешного парсинга стандартных функций или объектов , которые широко используются для WEB-а)
- может в коде возвращать объект Ast tree , чтобы мне можно было бы потом его использовать.

Comment: Народ , почему никто не отвечает ? (( Неужели никто не знает ?

Comment: Исправьте заголовок. Парсинг и интерпретация -- это все-таки разные вещи.

Answer (score 1):

А что мешает сделать форк [репозитория Jint](https://github.com/sebastienros/jint) и добавить свой visitor?

Кстати, существует паттерн [External Tree Visitor](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/language-implementation-patterns/9781680500097/f_0055.html), который инкапсулирует логику хождения по дереву в одном классе. В Jint у каждого `SyntaxNode` есть поле `Type`, по которому можно определить тип узла. В итоге, базовый класс visitor будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
public abstract class SyntaxVisitor
{
    public void Visit(SyntaxNode node)
    {
        switch (node.Type)
        {
            case SyntaxNodes.AssignmentExpression:
                VisitAssignmentExpression((AssignmentExpression)node);
                break;
            case SyntaxNodes.ArrayExpression:
                VisitArrayExpression((ArrayExpression)node);
                break;
            // и т.д.
            default:
                throw NotSupportedException($"Unsupported node type: {node.Type}");
        }
    }

    protected abstract void VisitAssignmentExpression(AssignmentExpression node);
    protected abstract void VisitArrayExpression(ArrayExpression node);
}
```

(Вообще, рекомендую книгу Language Implementation Patterns Теренса Парра – разработчика ANTLR).

Что касается реализации "стандартных функций" (по терминологии автора), привожу следующую цитату из документации к V8:

> The DOM is not, however, typically provided by the JavaScript engine
>   but instead by a browser. The same is true of V8—Google Chrome
>   provides the DOM. V8 does however provide all the data types,
>   operators, objects and functions specified in the ECMA standard.

Другими словами, все объекты DOM, вроде `window` и `document`, реализовываются не движком ECMAScript, а браузером. В спецификации ECMAScript есть `Global Object`, но нет `window`, и тем более нет `window.onload`, `document` и т.п. Если вам нужны объекты уровня браузера, то ищите браузерный движок. Одним JavaScript интерпретатором здесь не обойдешься; такая задача явно выходит за рамки "примитивного анализа кода".

Comment: либо можно попробовать объявить их как какие-нибудь дополнительные глобальные объекты. Возможно указанная библиотека поддерживает что-то подобное :)